# Ionic2 - Setting Default Field Value with Variable Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic2, angular2-formbuilder

I have a form in one of my components with a date picker. The constructor for this component looks like this.

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  private profileService: ProfileService) {
    this.formIsValid = true;

    let dobObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('current_profile')).stripeAccount.legal_entity.dob;
    let dob = (dobObj.year && dobObj.month && dobObj.day) ? dobObj.year + "-" + dobObj.month + "-" + dobObj.day : '';
    console.log(dob); // This prints "1999-12-31"

    this.dobForm = formBuilder.group({
      dob: [dob.toString(), Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

I get the following error message due to the dob.toString() that I am using to set the default value of my date picker.

```
WARN: Error parsing date: "null". Please provide a valid ISO 8601 datetime format: https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime
```

I console logged the value right before the formBuilder and the date prints out as expected. It seems like the string gets changed somehow before being used to set the default value in the formBuilder. If I hardcode the string "1999-12-31" in the formBuilder instead of using the variable, it works. I even checked to make sure that "dob === '1999-12-31'" was true.

Why does a hardcoded string work in setting the default value, but a variable with the exact same value not work?

EDIT:

This has got to be a bug with the date picker. If I input "1999-12-31" as the hard coded string, it works as expected. If I enter "1997-1-1" or "1997-12-3" it fails. It is accepting some valid dates, and not others.

EDIT 2:

Check this out:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private profileService: ProfileService, private loadingService: LoadingService) {
    this.formIsValid = true;

    //TODO: What??? Why is this happening?
    console.log(new Date("1997-1-1")); // null
    console.log(new Date("1999-12-31")); // "1999-12-31T00:00:00.000Z"
    console.log(new Date("2010-11-7")); // null
    console.log(new Date("1992-4-21")); // null
    console.log(new Date("1842-2-27")); // null
    console.log(new Date("2000-8-20")); // null

    this.dobForm = formBuilder.group({
      dob: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }
```

Why on Earth do so many strings fail to be parsed into dates? And what is the difference between "1999-12-31" and the others?

Comment: isn't dob a string already? it is not declared anywhere as a Date object literally.

Comment: yes it is a string already. I included the redundant cast just in case the data type was different or something. It doesn't work with, or without, the .toString()

Comment: is your input type date or string (text)?

Comment: The input type is an IOS 8601 datetime formatted string. i.e. "1999-12-31" or something equivalent.

Comment: did you try passing a date object instead? `dob: [new Date(dob.toString()), Validators.required]`. Alternatively, try: `dob: [new Date(dob.toString()).toISOString(), Validators.required];`

Comment: I have. That didn't work either. Get this though: simply console logging new Date("1997-1-1") is null whereas new Date("1999-12-31") is a date. Why is that? This has nothing to do with my project; it seems like a javascript issue?

Comment: Works properly here: https://jsfiddle.net/09jhL8yq/ . It should be something related to the format that the plugin itself is acquiring, perhaps it just accepts ISO 8601 compliant dates, and 1997-1-1 is not ISO 8601 compliant as far as I know, which is why I would rather wonder why the second case (the one with toISOString) doesn't work either. It should not be javascript-related though, despite I usually avoid using the date prototype and use instead some third party libraries like Momentjs.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this issue is your datepicker is taking `null` as value. In the code of datepicker, they don't have validation for `null` value.

Refer: source code from [https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/util/datetime-util.ts](http://Ionic%20Datepicker)

```
export function updateDate(existingData: DateTimeData, newData: any) {
  if (isPresent(newData) && newData !== '') {

    if (isString(newData)) {
      // new date is a string, and hopefully in the ISO format
      // convert it to our DateTimeData if a valid ISO
      newData = parseDate(newData);
      if (newData) {
        // successfully parsed the ISO string to our DateTimeData
        Object.assign(existingData, newData);
        return;
      }

    } else if ((isPresent(newData.year) || isPresent(newData.hour) || isPresent(newData.month) || isPresent(newData.day) || isPresent(newData.minute) || isPresent(newData.second))) {
      // newData is from of a datetime picker's selected values
      // update the existing DateTimeData data with the new values

      // do some magic for 12-hour values
      if (isPresent(newData.ampm) && isPresent(newData.hour)) {
        if (newData.ampm.value === 'pm') {
          newData.hour.value = (newData.hour.value === 12 ? 12 : newData.hour.value + 12);

        } else {
          newData.hour.value = (newData.hour.value === 12 ? 0 : newData.hour.value);
        }
      }

      // merge new values from the picker's selection
      // to the existing DateTimeData values
      for (var k in newData) {
        (<any>existingData)[k] = newData[k].value;
      }

      return;
    }

    // eww, invalid data
    console.warn(`Error parsing date: "${newData}". Please provide a valid ISO 8601 datetime format: https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime`);

  } else {
    // blank data, clear everything out
    for (var k in existingData) {
      delete (<any>existingData)[k];
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: But why is the date null? I edited the question with some new, relevant findings. Any ideas about what is going on to make the dates null?

Comment: I tried all the console statements (mentioned by you) on my machine. they are working fine. new Date() should not return null. Have you messed with your machine's date-time settings?

Comment: Are these console statements are displaying dates as null on console of "Developer Tool" ?

Comment: Have you messed with your browser's date-time or timezone ?

Comment: I haven't messed with my machine's date-time or timezone settings, nor my browser's. When I console log these dates in the developer console, they work fine. Only in my Ionic2 project do they log as null.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a '0' in front of the single digit dates, then the date can be created, like this:

```
console.log(new Date("2000-8-20"));  // null
console.log(new Date("2000-08-20")); // Sun Aug 20 2000 10:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)
```

To set a default value for the date picker, (as @briosheje pointed out) this works for me:

```
this.fromDate = new Date().toISOString();
```

Without that, I was getting the same parsing error as described in the question.